# Canvas: How to get the coordinates of the mouse pointer

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have an image (e.g. 4000x3000 pixel) in a canvas (e.g. visible 800x600 pixel, canvas total size 4000x3000 pixel) combined with scrollbars. If the user scrolls down/right to the right lower edge of the image and clicks the mouse button I would like to get the coordinate of the mouse pointer refering to the image (not to the visible canvas size). If the code is

```
bind .fr.c <ButtonRelease-1> {puts "%x / %y"}
```

I get the coordinate of the visible canvas e.g. 780/580 although the coordinate of the image is 3970/2970. How can I get these coordinates? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: How about `bind .fr.c <ButtonRelease-1> {puts "%X / %Y"}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the logical coordinate from the physical coordinate, you use the `canvasx` and `canvasy` methods.

```
bind .fr.c <ButtonRelease-1> {
    puts "[%W canvasx %x] / [%W canvasy %y]"
}
```